# Would like a universal way to split different strings into multiple parts using PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, split, uninstallation

I am working on a method of reading UninstallStrings for software from the registry. And then I'm trying to execute those strings to uninstall the software.

When I print out the variables that hold the string info, it prints the whole string (with the arguments) correctly, but I am unable to run those strings.
There are multiple parts to this issue.

Some install strings are formatted like so

```
c:\file path\blah\app.exe /uninstall
"c:\file path\blah\app.exe" /uninstall
c:\file path\blah\app.exe --uninstall
'c:\file path\blah\app.exe' /uninstall
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out the best way to be able to run the uninstaller in a "universal" way.
Is there a way to do this effectively?

I tried executing the strings 2 different ways.

```
    & $uninstaller
```

and

```
    Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c', $uninstaller -Wait
```

Neither of them seem to work. No errors, but they don't seem to run because when I check the app it's still installed.

And I tried splitting the text a few ways.

```
    $Uninstaller.split("/")[0]
    $Uninstaller.split("/",2)[1]
    $($Uninstaller) | Invoke-Expression
    $Uninstaller.Substring(0,$Uninstaller.lastIndexOf('.exe '))
    $Uninstaller.split('^(*?\.exe) *')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess that you need to enclose full path to `app.exe` in double quotes? E.g. the latter as `'c:\file path\blah\app.exe' /uninstall` to  `"c:\file path\blah\app.exe" /uninstall`?

Comment: Thank you for your response, the problem is, not all UninstallStrings in registry are in that syntax. That's what makes this a bit complicated. Some uninstall strings are msiexec, others are executable uninstallers with custom arguments. And not all arguments are universal. They are based on the executable.
One exe may have dashes, another a forward slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following testing script, where simple console application `CliParser.exe` merely echoes command line arguments (written in C, inspired [here](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINARGV)). Used the exact copy with a space in name `CliParser noPause.exe`; it shows that `. $Uninstaller $UninsParams` should work even if a path `$Uninstaller` contains space(s).

No need to use `Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe …`; just apply the dot-sourcing operator as `. $Uninstaller $UninsParams`…

The `$lines` collection contains an almost representative syntax patterns of uninstall strings (taken from my Windows 10):

```
$lines = @'
MsiExec.exe /X{FFC6E93A-B9AD-3F20-9B06-EE20E24AAEAF}
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Virtual Russian Keyboard\unins000.exe"
"C:\Windows10Upgrade\Windows10UpgraderApp.exe" /Uninstall
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe /package {CFEF48A8-BFB8-3EAC-8BA5-DE4F8AA267CE} /uninstall {815F0BC1-7E54-300C-9ACA-C9460FDF6F78} /qb+ REBOOTPROMPT=&quot;&quot;
C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{8833FFB6-5B0C-4764-81AA-06DFEED9A476}\Setup.exe -runfromtemp -removeonly
"C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RunDll32.EXE" "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2\InstallerCore\NVI2.DLL",UninstallPackage Display.Driver
%windir%\system32\sdbinst.exe -u "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\CustomSDB\{9f4f4a9b-eec5-4906-92fe-d1f43ccf5c8d}.sdb"
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$FakeUninstaller = "D:\bat\CLIParser noPause.exe"

foreach ( $line in $lines ) {
    # $line
    $aux = $line -split @('\.exe'),2,[System.StringSplitOptions]::None
    $Uninstaller = (cmd /c echo $($aux[0].TrimStart('"').TrimStart("'") + '.exe')).Trim('"')
    $UninsParams = $aux[1].TrimStart('"').TrimStart("'").Trim().split(' ',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

    ". $Uninstaller $UninsParams"
    . $FakeUninstaller $UninsParams | Where-Object { $_ -notlike "param 0 = *" }
}
```

**Output**: `D:\PShell\SO\62023960.ps1`

> ```
> . MsiExec.exe /X{FFC6E93A-B9AD-3F20-9B06-EE20E24AAEAF}
> param 1 = /X{FFC6E93A-B9AD-3F20-9B06-EE20E24AAEAF}
>
> . "D:\Program Files (x86)\Virtual Russian Keyboard\unins000.exe"
>
> . C:\Windows10Upgrade\Windows10UpgraderApp.exe /Uninstall
> param 1 = /Uninstall
>
> . C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe /package {CFEF48A8-BFB8-3EAC-8BA5-DE4F8AA267CE} /uninstall {815F0BC1-7E54-300C-9ACA-C9460FDF6F78} /qb+ REBOOTPROMPT=""
> param 1 = /package
> param 2 = {CFEF48A8-BFB8-3EAC-8BA5-DE4F8AA267CE}
> param 3 = /uninstall
> param 4 = {815F0BC1-7E54-300C-9ACA-C9460FDF6F78}
> param 5 = /qb+
> param 6 = REBOOTPROMPT=""
>
> . "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{8833FFB6-5B0C-4764-81AA-06DFEED9A476}\Setup.exe" -runfromtemp -removeonly
> param 1 = -runfromtemp
> param 2 = -removeonly
>
> . C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RunDll32.exe "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2\InstallerCore\NVI2.DLL",UninstallPackage Display.Driver
> param 1 = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2\InstallerCore\NVI2.DLL,UninstallPackage
> param 2 = Display.Driver
>
> . C:\WINDOWS\system32\sdbinst.exe -u "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\CustomSDB\{9f4f4a9b-eec5-4906-92fe-d1f43ccf5c8d}.sdb"
> param 1 = -u
> param 2 = C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\CustomSDB\{9f4f4a9b-eec5-4906-92fe-d1f43ccf5c8d}.sdb
> ```

Comment: Thank you for this share. This seems to actually be better than what I have posted below as my resolution. It essentially does the same thing with less lines of code, so I like yours better. 
The only thing I don't see to understand is the last line (the uninstaller piece), it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried using & $file, and still nothing.

Anyway, I got it to work by using 
Start-Process $Uninstaller -ArgumentList $UninsParams -wait

Comment: The `. $Uninstaller $UninsParams` could fail as `cmd` adds surrounding double quotes if `echo`ed string contains a space. For instance, `$y='a b'; echo $y; cmd /c echo $y; cmd /c "echo $y"` returns strings `a b`, `"a b"` and `a b`. However, properly escaping all double quotes in `cmd /c echo $($aux[0].TrimStart('"').TrimStart("'") + '.exe')` seems to be a tough problem. Could be done simply using an additional auxiliary variable, or as `$Uninstaller = (cmd /c echo $($aux[0].TrimStart('"').TrimStart("'") + '.exe')).Trim('"')`, see updated answer.

Comment: Hello, I made the adjustment. The last line that you have, I adjusted to fit my example using:
    . $Uninstaller $UninsParams | Where-Object { $_ -notlike "param 0 = *" }
However, I get this error:
". : The term '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive\20.064.0329.0008_7\OneDriveSetup.exe"' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Adjusted (in answer) missing most left opening parenthesis in `$Uninstaller = (cmd /c echo $($aux[0].TrimStart('"').TrimStart("'") + '.exe')).Trim('"')`…

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Maybe there's a better way to do it, but this seems to work for me.

```
CLS

$Software = "OneDrive"
$Filter = "*" + $Software + "*"
$Program = $ProgUninstall = $FileUninstaller = $FileArg = $NULL

try 
{
    if (Test-Path -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node") 
    {
        $programs = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" -ErrorAction Stop
    }

    $programs += Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" -ErrorAction Stop
    $programs += Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::\HKEY_USERS\*\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} 
catch 
{
    Write-Error $_
    break
}

foreach($Program in $Programs)
{
    $ProgDisplayName = $Program.DisplayName
    $ProgUninstall = $Program.UninstallString

    if($ProgDisplayName -like $Filter)
    {
        if($ProgUninstall -like "msiexec*")
        {
            $FileUninstaller = $ProgUninstall.split(" ")[0]
            $FileArg = ($($ProgUninstall).split(" ",2)[1])
        }
        else
        {
            if(($ProgUninstall -like '"*"*') -or ($ProgUninstall -like "'*'*"))
            {
                #String has quotes, don't need to do anything

            }
            else
            {
                if($NULL -ne $ProgUninstall)
                {
                    #String doesn't have quotes so we should add them
                    $ProgUninstall = '"' + ($ProgUninstall.Replace('.exe','.exe"'))                    
                }
            }

            #Let's grab the uninstaller and arguments
            $FileUninstaller = $ProgUninstall.split('"')[1]
            $FileArg = $ProgUninstall.split('"')[-1]
        }

        #Debug
        #$FileUninstaller
        #$FileArg

        #Run the Uninstaller
        Start-Process $FileUninstaller -ArgumentList $FileArg -wait -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works very easily for msi installs:

```
get-package *whatever* | uninstall-package
```

Here's a non-msi silent uninstall example, but you have to add "/S" or whatever the silent uninstall option is:

```
get-package notepad++* | 
  % { & $_.Meta.Attributes['UninstallString'] /S }
```

Comment: Thank you for the updated response, but with my situation I want it to be as seamless as possible. I posted a solution I figured out that seemed to work well for me down below, but JoesefZ's solution seems to be better. It's the exact same output as mine (which is what I need), with less code, so I feel that's the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

here's a rewrite of JosefZ 's code converted into an argument parsing function  and a execution example

```
function Parse-UninstallLines {
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$InputString
        )
    
        $lines = $InputString -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
        $result = @()
    
        foreach ($line in $lines) {
            $aux = $line -split @('\.exe'), 2, [System.StringSplitOptions]::None
            $Uninstaller = (cmd /c echo $($aux[0].TrimStart('"').TrimStart("'") + '.exe')).Trim('"')
            $UninsParams = $aux[1].TrimStart('"').TrimStart("'").Trim().split(' ', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    
            $item = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Uninstaller = $Uninstaller
                UninsParams = $UninsParams
            }
    
            $result += $item
        }
    
        return $result
    }

#usage example 
$UninstallString=""C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{e87d9247-916d-4f99-b417-022ca8af19e3}\windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.16-win-x86.exe" /uninstall /quiet"

$Progs=Parse-UninstallLines -inputString $UninstallString
$executable = $Progs.Uninstaller
$arguments = $Progs.UninsParams

$process = Start-Process -FilePath $executable -ArgumentList "$arguments /quiet" -PassThru
```